# Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock ethernet 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, ethernet, docking

Coming from a Dell E series to the Lenovo X1 Carbon (5th Gen).  Got the Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 dock to go with it.  Had to disable thunderbolt security in the BIOS to get the USB and other ports working.  Can't get the ethernet working.  It only sees the internal ethernet card.  I saw somewhere else that it is a realtek 8152, and I looked at dmsg and found this:

```
[    3.505021] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    3.647253] r8152 6-1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown version 0x6010
[    3.647255] r8152 6-1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown Device
```

Not sure where to go from here.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 17ef:3069 Lenovo 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 17ef:3066 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13ba:0017 PCPlay PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:306a Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5ce Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Yes, docked

usb-devices | awk '/17ef/' RS=

```
T:  Bus=06 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=5000 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=17ef ProdID=3069 Rev=31.03
S:  Manufacturer=Lenovo
S:  Product=ThinkPad TBT3 LAN
S:  SerialNumber=301000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=288mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Is it in docked state?

Comment: Please also add output of `usb-devices | awk '/17ef/' RS=`

Comment: If it is really `r8152` device, then it is not hard to add the id to the kernel driver. But I am not quite sure. I can build a test module for you next week.

Comment: That is info that I got somewhere else, I think on the lenovo forum.  I guess I can check what driver is used in Windows.  I'm headed out.  I'll update on Tuesday.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Did you see this https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/X1-5th-and-Thundebolt3-dockstation-no-ethernet-with-Debian/td-p/3730394

Comment: FWIW, here is another advise : don't forget to activate the Thunderbolt interface in the BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `6010` version of this `r8152` device is not supported by the `4.10` kernel.

But it is supported by the `4.13-rc6` kernel version. It has been added by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/usb/r8152.c?h=v4.13-rc5&id=65b82d696b9e84fda6dd7df61801b57d3e7fb976).

You will be able to install it from [Ubuntu mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13-rc6/).